# How to find text between less and greater than, then strip the <> in Java?

Tags: java, charat

I don't know how to find these words.. example I have this text...

```
The other day I went to the <location> and bought some <plural-noun> . Afterwards, I went to <location> , but it was very <adjective> so I left quickly and went to <location> .
```

I don't know what to search cause when I search `<` and `>` on google, it will be ignored. Need help how to get this string.

so I will get the `<location>`, `<plural-noun>`, `<location>`, `<adjective>`, `<location>`

I must use the `charAt()` method. My attempt:

```
String string = this.fileName;
for(int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++)
                if((string.charAt(i) == '<') && (string.charAt(i) == '>'))
                    System.println(""); //<-------- IM STUCK HERE
```

I don't know... almost two days no sleep.

My current but one last problem... How to remove `<` and `>` on each word on display?

```
String string = this.template;
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<.*?>");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        List<String> listMatches = new ArrayList<String>();

        while(matcher.find()) {
            listMatches.add(matcher.group());
        }
        // System.out.println(listMatches.size());
        int indexNumber = 1;
         for(String s : listMatches) {
             System.out.println(Integer.toString(indexNumber) + ". " + s);
             indexNumber++;
         }
```

Comment: Why do you have to use the charAt() method?  This can be solved using regular expressions.

Comment: @Brad updated on new...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes.

1. Search for regex Pattern `<.*?>`.
2. Find the pattern with Matcher.

Comment: Why not `<.+>` for the pattern?

Comment: how do I match it using this? `Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)\\]");` I want only `<` and `>`

Comment: Not working on this... `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<.+>");`

Comment: it's working... do you know how to remove `<`and `>` on each string?

Comment: If you don't want the angle brackets, you could try lookaheads and lookbehinds.  I think the correct expression would be `Pattern.compile("(?<=<).+(?=>)")`

Comment: @DavidWallace i want it because I will change the string on that base on user inputs. But on displaying first I must not show the `<` and `>` is that possible? or I will use this again and more code...

Comment: I don't understand  your comment - but the expression I gave will allow you to search for words WITH the madonnas, but give the result WITHOUT the madonnas.  So in the String `apple <banana> cherry` it will match `banana`.  Isn't that what you want?

Answer (score 2):

There are really two questions here, so I'll answer only the last one; when you have the `<text>` that you want, go like this:

```
String text = "<the_text_you_want>";

text.replace("<","").replace(">","").replace("-"," ");
```

That will get rid of the delimiters.

Comment: thanks, do you know how to change `plural-noun` into `plural noun` ?

Comment: `Thanks for the feedback! Once you earn a total of 15 reputation, your votes will change the publicly displayed post score.` can't upvote sorry dude... I will upvote if I reach 15

Answer (score 1):

Read the whole line and store it in, say `String line`. Then, use:

```
String line = "The other day I went to the <location> and bought some <plural-noun> . Afterwards, I went to <location> , but it was very <adjective> so I left quickly and went to <location> ."; 

boolean found = false;
String data[] = new String[20];
int counter = 0;

Arrays.fill(data, "");

for(int i = 0; i < line.length() && counter < 20; i++) {
    if(line.charAt(i) == '<')
        found = true;
    else if(line.charAt(i) == '>' && found) {
        found = false;
        counter++;
    }
    else if(found) {
        data[counter] += line.charAt(i);
    }
}

for(int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
    System.out.println("Scanned data #" + (i + 1) + " = " + data[i]);
```